# Using FiddlerScript to extract unique values of a request header across all requests

Tags: fiddler

I'm studying FiddlerScript in order to see if it could be used to extract unique values of a given request header across all requests in a SAZ file.

To piece together what I want to achieve I think these bits are necessary:

**Find a way to execute the Fiddler script based on user gesture**

I found a way to make a menu with a menu item in the default FiddlerScript Rules file. This seems sufficient:

```cs
QuickLinkMenu("Tom")
QuickLinkItem("Do a thing", "")
public static function DoLinksMenu(text: string, action: string) {
  FiddlerApplication.…
}
```

I also found [QuickExec](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledgebase/quickexec) as an alternative, so this area should be covered.

**Find a way to extract a header value from each request**

```cs
FiddlerApplication.DoImport("saz", false, null, null, null)
```

The above line should return `Session[]` which can be then iterated through. This line doesn't do anything for me, I tried to use `FiddlerObject.log` to see why, but I am not sure where to find the log results. [Logging](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/logging) doesn't say where to find the logs.

**Log the unique values somewhere and find a way to view this log**

As touched upon above, I am able (I think) to log stuff, just not able to view the log.

---

At the moment I can't get past not being able to log/debug.

Comment: You can use FiddlerApplication.DoImport method to import SAZ file in a custom button. Then you can loop through the `Session[]` and extract/log the needed information from the requests/responses. This docs is for FiddlerCore, but the same method should be available in FidlerScript as well: https://docs.telerik.com/fiddlercore/api/fiddler.fiddlerapplication#collapsible-Fiddler_FiddlerApplication_DoImport_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_System_String_System_Object__System_EventHandler_Fiddler_ProgressCallbackEventArgs__Fiddler_GetPasswordDelegate_

Comment: @BorislavIvanov I have updated the question to reflect this. Can you help me with how to access the log?

Comment: Yep, the API is far than perfect :) Maybe try to include the path to the `.saz` file as in [this code sample](https://github.com/gocardless/gocardless-legacy-dotnet/blob/master/GoCardlessSdk.Tests/libs/FiddlerCoreAPI/SampleApp/Program.cs#L55-L58)